# how check is a google sheet is public or private with javascript

Tags: javascript

does anyone know if it is possible to check with javascript if a google sheet is public?
I need in my script to check if the sheet has been published or not, it would help so much. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share code.

Comment: For example, how about checking the file ID using the method of "Files: get" of Drive API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) When the file is not publicly shared, an error occurs. When the file is publicly shared, the file information is returned. But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.